# Upgrading Grails from v3.0 to v3.1 or v3.2

Tags: grails, grails3

I'm in process of upgrading an app from Grails v2 to v3 .
I got to a point where it works reasonably well with Grails 3.0.17. 
I wanted to upgrade it to v3.1 or v3.2. But after changing the version in `gradle.properties` that's what I get after executing `grails run-app`:

```
me@host:[~/](feature/grails3-migration) : grails run-app
| Error Error occurred running Grails CLI: startup failed:
script14867378818131525390840.groovy: 3: unable to resolve class xxx.yyy.CollectorsJob
 @ line 3, column 1.
   import xxx.yyy.jobs.CollectorsJob
   ^

script14867378818131525390840.groovy: 6: unable to resolve class xxx.yyy.domain.business.Company
 @ line 6, column 1.
   import xxx.yyy.domain.business.Company
   ^

script14867378818131525390840.groovy: 5: unable to resolve class xxx.yyy.domain.access.User
 @ line 5, column 1.
   import xxx.yyy.domain.access.User
   ^
...
```

There's about 15 errors like that printed.

What's the problem here? I've tried `clear` the project and change the jdk version fro 1.8 -> 1.7. Each time the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are referencing application classes in `grails-app/conf/application.groovy` these will need to be moved to your runtime configuration in `grails-app/conf/runtime.groovy`

The `application.groovy` file is parsed by the build system in addition to the runtime so cannot contain references to classes that are not yet compiled

Comment: Thanks! That's obviously the problem. Of course now I see that mentioned in the Grails 3.2 migration guide not in 3.1 though.